# Animating the bounds property of a UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

According to the Apple documentation available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1) the `bounds` property of a UIView can be animated.

In order to programmatically rotate one of my views (in this case from portrait to landscape), I implemented the following code:

```
 float w = controlsView.bounds.size.width;
 float h = controlsView.bounds.size.height;

 CGAffineTransform T = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);

 UIViewContentMode oldContentMode = controlsView.contentMode;
 controlsView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        controlsView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, h, w);
        controlsView.transform = T;
 }];

 controlsView.contentMode = oldContentMode;
```

I added the two instructions for `contentMode` because I have read somewhere on StackOverflow that `contentMode` must be set to that value in order for a UIView to redraw the content while the `bounds` property is modified (however, in this case it does not affect the behaviour in any way).

The problem of that code is that UIView is not resized with an animation but all at once.

Executing that code, the UIView is first resized (without animation) then rotated with an animation.

How can I animate the resizing?

**-- UPDATE --**

I tried to combine a scaling and rotating transformation. The UIView rotates and scales in an animation, but at the end its `bounds` property does not change: even if it has been rotated to a landscape orientation (which should be 568x320 on my iPhone), its width and height stay at the portrait values (320x568). Indeed, the UI controls on the `controlsView` are deformed (wrong aspect ratio) and appears stretched.

Comment: Why not use a scale and rotate transform?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me using *UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews* (Swift):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,delay:0.0,
options:UIViewAnimationOptions.LayoutSubviews,
animations:{ () -> Void in
  myView.transform = myRotationTransform
  myView.bounds = myBounds
}, completion: nil)
```

(no explicit scaling nor changing contentMode)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you set a `transform` property, all other transforms (`bounds`) are overwritten. To fix it you have to create one `transform` that combines **scaling** and **rotating**.

Example:

```
CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
{
    controlsView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(scaleTransform, M_PI/2);
}];
```

You will need to calculate the scaling `X` and `Y` values based on the size you want to have at the end of the animations. You might also want to change the `anchorPoint` property to set a center point used for scaling (`controlsView.layer.anchorPoint`).

Comment: According to the documentation I should be able to animate the `bounds` property when using a particular `trasnform`. This is what the doc reports for the `frame` property:

Modify this property to change the view’s size and position relative to its superview’s coordinate system. (If the transform property does not contain the identity transform, modify the bounds or center properties instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Animating your bounds doesn't change its value. It reverts to its original value once the animation ends.

Change the value of the bounds to the final value once the animation is over. I'll solve the trouble.